# Details of the Baal Shem Tov and Baal HaTanya debate with misnagdim

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

It’s pretty well known that the Baal Hatanya had a debate with misnagdim and the Baal Shem Tov once agreed to be farhered by them.(both sides agree that it happened)

Does anyone have the actual details of the questions asked and the answers given?

Please no loshon hora, machlokes  or stories that anyone can make up later on in time. Only actual recorded  questions with actual recorded answers.

Comment: The first Lubavitcher Rebbe was 15 when the Baal Shem Tov died, so this story of them debating together sounds unlikely

Comment: They happened  at separate times. The Baal Shem Tov had a farher. The Baal HaTanya had a debate.

Comment: Do you have a source that "both sides agree that it happened"?

Comment: I've seen and heard both sides say over stories claiming that their side won over the other side. With the exception of an equivocal answer    the Baal Shem Tov gave to an unknown question  which both sides debate what he meant neither side gives details.

Comment: @Schmerel if you edit your question to clarify in  response to comments then the comments can be deleted

Answer (score 1):

There is in the writings of the 6th Lubavitcher Rebbe written the whole story how the Baal HaTanya debated with Misnagdim.

To read online: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/81908/jewish/Supplement-A-The-Debate-in-Minsk.htm

To buy:
https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=EFR-DEBA

Comment: He just writes  the story. The other side is going to give a different version from their perspective.  What were the actual questions and answers?